# Domain name not working on port other than 80 in unbuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, openssl

I am using vps with ubuntu 16.4.My project's frontend is using angular 7 and backend is in nodejs.
I have configured domain (say:example.com) at the IP address of VPS.

My frontend code is placed in /var/www/html folder and running at port 80.I can access it through **http://example.com**.This code sends request to nodejs server which is running at port 4300.

**server.js(NodeJS):**

```
  var express = require('express');
  var https = require('https');
  var fs = require('fs');

  var options = {
   key: fs.readFileSync('../Path_to_ssl_key/server.key'),
   cert: fs.readFileSync('../Path_to_ssl_certificate/server.crt')
  };

  var app = express();
  app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.json({message:"Response from server"})
  });

  https.createServer(options, app).listen(4300,'0.0.0.0',function(){
    console.log("https server is up at 1000.");
  });
```

Expected behavior is this must be accessible at https://example.com:4300.but it is not accessible at domain name.while it can be accessed at IP:4300 which obviously causing ssl to not work correctly.

My question is what can be the possible reason this nodejs server is not accessible at domain name despite of forwarding IP address of VPS to example.com?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked for any kind of firewall/ip filtering that is blocking non-standard ports?

Comment: yes checked ufw status it is inactive.